# How do I set which Apache / PHP 10.6 should run?

Tags: macports, apache

All my problems stemmed from trying to get mcrypt for PHP installed. Last night I gave in and [followed a tutorial](http://blog.binarypie.com/snow-leopard-106-and-php-532) of how to do a totally fresh apache2 and php5.3.3 install. I did this using MacPorts.

Sadly, that didn't enable mcrypt for me last night, although I was pretty pleased that I got 5.3.3 running. :)

The problem is that I have woken up this morning to find that my php version is back down to 5.3.1 which can only mean that OS X has reverted to my original Apache and PHP.

**How to I tell OS X to use the software I installed via MacPorts?**

*(And then I will as a new question of how to enable mcrypt)*

Comment: If you only want answers to match "How to I tell OSX to use the software I installed via macports?", perhaps you should edit your question. Because, you're asking two different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not so much your version of Apache/PHP have been reverted - it's just the wrong version is loaded.

If you have Mac OS X's Web Sharing enabled it will auto enable the version of Apache and PHP Apple provides using the LaunchDaemon `org.apache.httpd.plist` in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons` (this will override MacPorts version). You'll want to disable this by either turning off Web Sharing in the Sharing Preference Pane or by running `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`.

When you installed Apache for MacPorts it installed a LaunchDaemon into `/Library/LaunchDaemons` which if enabled will start up the MacPorts version of Apache automatically. To enable it run `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.apache2.plist` and you're off to the races.

If you're running `apachectl` to restart - make sure you've selected the right version. You may need to alter your $PATH to have `/opt/local/apache2/bim` before `/usr/sbin`

As for what version of PHP is being used; on the command line this will depend on your $PATH while for Apache it's entirely in your configuration of where the libphp5 module is. (`/etc/apache2/` for the built in version, `/opt/local/apache2/conf` for the version MacPorts installed)

Answer (score 1):

Why does OS X need to know which Apache to use?  Just run the correct Apache yourself.  Open up Terminal, `cd` to the MacPorts directory containing the correct Apache (probably `/opt/something/something/something/Apache2/bin` or something like that), and run it (probably something like `./httpd`).

Answer (score 1):

You have two solutions :

1. You have to edit the global `PATH` variable to add MacPort folders at the beginning. It contains the order of folders the system uses to find binaries.
2. Backup original binaries (in `/usr/bin`, `/bin`, …), then add symlinks to MacPorts binaries.

Normally, **do not use** option 2 until you really know what you're doing. I just mentioned it because it's technically possible.

To edit the global `PATH` variable, edit the file `/etc/paths`, add `/opt/local/bin` at the beginning and finally reboot to apply changes.

You can control, after the reboot, that changes have been made by do the following command :

> echo $PATH

You should see `/opt/local/bin` just before `/usr/bin:/bin:…`.